What does the duration in "Rendered at" section mean?
What does the 5.8s for 24.2ms means?
Found the source code react-devtools-shared/src/devtools/views/Profiler/SidebarSelectedFiberInfo.js#L97
const listItems = [];
  let i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < commitIndices.length; i++) {
    const commitIndex = commitIndices[i];

    const {duration, timestamp} = profilerStore.getCommitData(
      ((rootID: any): number),
      commitIndex,
    );

    listItems.push(
      <button
        key={commitIndex}
        ref={selectedCommitIndex === commitIndex ? selectedListItemRef : null}
        className={
          selectedCommitIndex === commitIndex
            ? styles.CurrentCommit
            : styles.Commit
        }
        onClick={() => selectCommitIndex(commitIndex)}>
        {formatTime(timestamp)}s for {formatDuration(duration)}ms
      </button>,
    );
  }

Don't know what are duration and timestamp means.


During your recorded period the selected component was rendered at 5.8 and 5.9 seconds into the recording. The first time it took 24.2ms to render the second time it took 23.4ms to render. You should be able to click on the items under "Rendered At:" to jump to each of the individually recorded renders.

@JacobSmit Thanks. 5.8s means the duration of the component committed time and the profiling record start time. So committed time - profiling record start time = 5.8s. Is this correct? And the 23.4ms is the render time of the component?

The 5.8s means 5.8 seconds after you hit the little red record button, this component started (not triggered) a rerender which took 24.2ms to complete.

@JacobSmit Thanks. Got it. Can you post an answer?

"Rendered at:" lists all the time points at which that specific component rendered (initial / rerenders) during the recorded period.
The initial time value (5.8s in the screenshot) is how long since the start of recording (the little red circle was pressed) the component started (not triggered) a render.
The second time value (24.2ms in the screenshot) is how long the component took to complete the render.
